# onSelectAll even only returns one by one instead of model

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I am using **"angular dropdown multiselect"** and on "onSelectAll" event I want to get the selected model.But its giving one by one.

**HTML:**

```
      <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example13data" selected-model="example13model" extra-settings="example13settings" events="{ onItemSelect: dropdownChange,onItemDeselect:dropdownChange,onSelectAll:dropdownChange,onUnselectAll:dropdownChange }" translation-texts="example5customTexts"></div>
      <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example14data" selected-model="example14model" extra-settings="example14settings" events="{ onItemSelect: dropdownChange,onItemDeselect:dropdownChange,onSelectAll:dropdownChange,onUnselectAll:dropdownChange }" translation-texts="example6customTexts"></div>

    {{example13model}}
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

        myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope',
          function($scope) {

            $scope.example13model = [];
            $scope.example13data = [{
                        "regionName": "ALAC",
                        "regionId": 178
                    }, {
                        "regionName": "ANZ",
                        "regionId": 177
                    }];
          $scope.example5customTexts = {buttonDefaultText: 'Geo'};
            $scope.example13settings = {
              smartButtonMaxItems: 3,
              displayProp: 'regionName',
              idProp: 'regionId'
            };
            $scope.example14model = [];
            $scope.example14data = [{
                        "countryName": "India",
                        "regionId": 178
                    }, {
                        "countryName": "ANZ",
                        "regionId": 177
                    }];
          $scope.example6customTexts = {buttonDefaultText: 'Country'};
            $scope.example14settings = {
              smartButtonMaxItems: 3,
              displayProp: 'countryName',
              idProp: 'regionId'
            };
            $scope.dropdownChange = function(item){
              console.log($scope.example13model);
              $scope.example14data = [{
                        "countryName": "USA",
                        "regionId": 178
                    }];
            };
          }
        ]);
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]
[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/hfQFI2LLKUZyvFpgai0S?p=preview)

How can I get the multiselect model at once.

Comment: How you will define user has finished selecting all the option?

Comment: Consider user will click "All" directly and based on that I have to do some stuff.